Blender 4.2 & 4.3 - Alpha over node not working correctly, now clips final render in versions 4.2 and 4.3
All,
When using Blender version 4.2 or 4.3 after a final render I use the compositor to overlay the final render over a background image. I use the transform node to scale and move the background image to the desired location. however in these latest versions this now crops the final render.
this does not occur in 4.1 or lower versions.
Is there a setting I haven't changed or is this a known bug


Are you sure it's not the other way around, left is 4.1 and right is 4.2 4.3 ?

No, 100% sure 4.2/4.3 is where the issue is occuring.

Then I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended behavior. One thing is sure, compositing had a few fundamental changes on how it works. Hopefully someone can answer your question.

You need a Background, in this case a transparent one, combine that to your actual image background and then to the render https://imgur.com/a/VOtQqJ3

To further illustrate this, see the image of an example scene below. I have created a very simple scene for demonstration. When trying to underlay the image behind the render, you lose the entire scene.
The only workaround I can think of is to edit the background image in Photoshop, adding a colored background with the image positioned correctly. However, this approach feels tedious.
I'm wondering if there's an alpha option available elsewhere that could be used.


I'm not 100% sure but I believe this change is what you are experiencing : 4.2 Release notes - Clipping. This is the new behavior, not a bug.
From the release notes of 4.2 :

The old compositor will clip images if their inferred size is smaller than their actual size, while the new compositor will not do size inference and consequently will not clip images.


thanks. If this is the case how do you resize a background image and position behind the final render without clipping the foreground

This change should stop clipping, if you really have clipping with 4.2 then it's probably not caused by this change. It may be linked but I don't understand enough to say.
